# Work with merge of multiple git branches

Tags: git, merge

I have 2 branches, A and B, that don't conflict with each other and have master as an ancestor. I'd like to work with the result of merging the two branches together into AB, for testing, but only make code changes to A or B. The problem is that every time I commit a change to A or B, I have to delete AB and remake it- merging the changes makes a really ugly history and strikes me as being unnecessary. I've looked into rebase, but it doesn't behave well when merge commits are involved. Is there an easy solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [branch per feature](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/) work-flow: feature-a-branch, feature-b-branch, and project-qa branch for integrating a and b.

project-qa can branch off master at the common ancestor commit or when work started for new sprint.

Merge both feature branches into it as changes occur and release the qa branch. Merge project-qa into master when released.

[image]

More info:

http://codingsolutions.blogspot.ca/2011/07/using-branch-per-feature-cleanup-across.html

Comment: This is what I'm doing. My question is more about keeping the commit history clean- the QA branch becomes just a series of obselete merge commits as more commits come in on feature-a and feature-b. I'm more wondering if there's an easy way, besides constantly deleting and remaking qa, to have a working directory that is the merge of feature a and feature b.